# Exception while calling service, underlying cause: could not execute query

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

Overnight I started a migration from a TFS 2010 server to VSO. The last time I looked at the status of the migration it was 90% done with the migration of work items and had already begun migrating version control.

Today, I received this message:

[image: OpsHub tool error]

The message persisted even though I restarted the OpsHub utility and even restarted the computer. How do I proceed?

Comment: Hi, do you have any other application utilizing the 8989 port? Can you verify this?

Comment: Only java.exe and ovsmu.exe are utilizing port 8989. I verified this by using "netstat -aon > log.txt" in an elevated command prompt and then looking at the process id's.

Comment: Can you share the logs from "C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs" to ovsmu@opshub.com. Another point, when you run the utility and encounter this error, can you verify from Windows Services if "OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility" service is running..?